# statistically significant difference of linear combination of variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a mathematical model according to which a quantity I can measure experimentally, x, is equal to a linear combination of two other variables, y and z: x=ay+bz. I can measure experimentally x and y in different treatments and would like to know if z changes. I have no way of measuring z, nor a and b. How can I detect if z changes in a statistically significant way from the control treatment, not knowing the values of a and b?

I have attempted this by computing the T statistics for x across two treatments, which would be:
$$T=\frac{a (\langle y_1 \rangle-\langle y_2\rangle)+b(\langle z_1 \rangle-\langle z_2\rangle)}{\sqrt{a^2(Var[y_1]+Var[y_2])+b^2 (Var[z_1]+Var[z_2])}}$$
thus:
$$T=\frac{\langle y_1 \rangle-\langle y_2\rangle+b/a(\langle z_1 \rangle-\langle z_2\rangle)}{\sqrt{Var[y_1]+Var[y_2]+(b/a)^2 (Var[z_1]+Var[z_2])}}$$
so it looks like I would need to know a/b to say something about the difference between the mean values of x across the two treatments? Is there any way to get around this?

This sounds a bit strange to me because it means that the unit of measurement with which y and z are measured are important (as they would affect a and b), while intuitively I would have said that they don't.

Comment: What do you know about the measurement variances?  What exactly does it mean for $z$ to "change" -- is it one constant value within each treatment group, or does it vary around some typical value in each group and you want to see whether those typical values differ? Or are you doing a sequence of observations over time and wanting to know whether there's a trend in $z$?  Are $a$ and $b$ constant or not?

Comment: Hi, all variables are continuous, a and b are constants. I typically observe that x decreases and y increases. I'm working under the assumption that x, y and z are gaussian, with y and z independent of each other. For each treatment, I have one value of x and one value of y.

Comment: I should also say that I have multiple technical replicates per treatment

Comment: Please add this new information in comments as an edit to the post. We wanr posts to be self-contained, and, comments are easily overseen, and can be deleted